# Black and white ball drawing without replacement expected number of ball color switches

Tags: probability, combinatorics, random-walk

We randomly draw balls one by one without replacement from an urn with $w$ white balls and $b$ black balls until the urn is emptied. We call the event of a consecutive appearance of two balls of distinct colors a color switch. What is the expected number of color switches in this process?

We can model this as a random walk on a lattice. I do not think the probability of a color switch at a pair of given consecutive draws starting at the $i$'th draw is independent of $i$. Am I right?

Comment: Say you have `WWB`, would this be a color switch? Say you have `BWWW`, would this be two color switches?

Comment: @MatthewAnderson: I state "a consecutive appearance of two balls of distinct colors". Thus your two examples each has $1$ color switch.

Answer (score 6):

> I do not think the probability of a color switch at a pair of given consecutive draws starting at the $i^{th}$ draw is independent of $i$.

No, it is *identical* for all $i$ in $1$ to $b+w-1$.

The probability for a colour switch after draw $i$ (call this event $S_i=1$), is the probability that draw $i$ is one colour and draw $i+1$ is the other. $$\forall i{\in}\{1,..,b{+}w{-}1\}~~, ~~\mathsf P(S_i{=}1)=\dfrac{\ldots}{\ldots~\ldots}$$

That will help you find the expectation.

---

For the variance, note that events $S_i{=}1, S_j{=}1$ are not going to be independent.$$\mathsf P(S_i{=}1,S_j{=}1)=\begin{cases}\mathsf P(S_i{=}1) &:& i=j, i{\in}\{1,..,b{+}w{-}1\},j{\in}\{1,..,b{+}w{-}1\}\\\ldots &:& \lvert i-j\rvert=1, i{\in}\{1,..,b{+}w{-}1\},j{\in}\{1,..,b{+}w{-}1\}\\\ldots &:&\lvert i-j\rvert>1, i{\in}\{1,..,b{+}w{-}1\},j{\in}\{1,..,b{+}w{-}1\}\\0&:& i{\notin}\{1,..,b{+}w{-}1\} \lor j{\notin}\{1,..,b{+}w{-}1\} \end{cases}$$

Comment: Hint: There are 26 black cards and 26 red cards in a standard deck.  Think about the probability that there is a switch at some particular point in the deck.

Comment: You are right. +1 The key is that $P(S_i)$'s are equal for all $i$'s. I have detailed my reason for the equality in my two answers. It would be nice if you would explicate your rationale for $i$-independence.

Comment: $\{S_i{=}1, S_{i+1}{=}1\}$ is the event that the $i^{th}$ and $(i{+}2)^{nd}$ draw are the same colour while $(i{+}1)$ draw is the other.

Comment: I was asking about the independence of $P(S_i)$ with respect to $i$, not about$P(S_i, S_{i+1})$.

Comment: There is not much more to say.  The probability measure for the event as described, $S_i$, is not affected by the position in the drawing (as long as $1\leq i\leq b+w-1$).

Comment: I realized that as shown in detail in my two answers. I just wonder if you have a different and succinct way of proving that $S_i$ is not affected by $i$.

Answer (score 2):

There are $b+w-1$ consecutive pairs.

Number the draws chronologically and for $i=1,\dots,b+w-1$ let $X_i$ take value $1$ if  pair $(i,i+1)$ produces a switch. Let $X_i$ take value $0$ otherwise.

Then $X:=\sum_{i=1}^{b+w-1}X_i$ denotes the total number of switches and the $X_i$ have equal distribution.

With linearity of expectations and symmetry we find:$$\mathbb EX=(b+w-1)P(X_1=1)=(b+w-1)\frac{2wb}{(b+w)(b+w-1)}=\frac{2wb}{b+w}$$

Actually this is not more than a work-out of the answer of Graham.

---

**addendum**

The balls are placed on the spots $1,2,\dots, b+w$.

For $i\in\{1,2,\dots,b+w-1\}$ let $W_i$ denote the event that a white ball will cover spot $i$ and let $B_i$ denote the event that a black ball will cover spot $i$.

Then: $$P(W_i\cap B_{i+1})=P(W_i)P(B_{i+1}\mid W_i)=\frac{w}{b+w}\frac{b}{b+w-1}$$

To understand this let it land that *all original balls have equal probability to become the ball that covers spot* $i$, so that for each of them this probability is $\frac1{b+w}$.

Then - since $w$ of these balls are white - the probability that a white ball will do that is $\frac{w}{b+w}$, which is expressed in $P(W_i)=\frac{w}{b+w}$.

Under the condition that this indeed happens there are $b+w-1$ equiprobable candidates left for covering spot $i+1$ and $b$ of them are black so that $P(B_{i+1}\mid W_i)=\frac{b}{b+w-1}$

Similarly we find that: $$P(B_i\cap W_{i+1})=\frac{b}{b+w}\frac{w}{b+w-1}$$

Then: $$P(X_i=1)=P(W_i\cap B_{i+1})+P(B_i\cap W_{i+1})=\frac{2wb}{(b+w)(b+w-1)}$$

This for every $i$.

Comment: You are right. I have worked out the same answer. The key is that $P(X_i)$ are equal for all $i$. It would be better if you would explain that in detail.

Comment: I have added something to make clear why the distribution of $X_i$ does not depend on $i$.

Comment: +1. Good explanation.

Comment: In situations like this it is handsome to personalize with a spot who is wondering something like: "hmm.. I will be covered by a ball. Well, what are my chances to be covered by a white ball then?" Thinking like that often opens up new perspectives in probability theory that are astonishing simple. As human beings though we have some sort of reluctance against personalizing with things that are not human so that unfortunately the door stays closed.

Comment: Hmm, I am not sure how personalization per se inspires more intuition than otherwise. I was initially led astray by thinking of the path-dependent probability of getting a, say, white ball on the $i$'th draw, with or without considering the subsequence draw, conditioned on having observed the previous colors.

Comment: Small example then. Lots of times I have seen students struggling with questions like: "if there are $2$ blue balls and $3$ red balls and I take out one by one two balls, then what is the probability that the second ball is red?" Conversion to: "what is the probability that the second spot will be covered by a red ball?" opens their eyes and enriches their intuition (Oh,... of course!).

Comment: Perhaps you choose the wrong word using "personalization". I think it is more like visualizing the whole path and all the possible paths or samples of a process/sample space rather than thinking of a process one time-step at a time, if you know what I am saying.

Comment: My use of the term "personalization" is quite subjective,  I think. The essence is the change of perspective (how would I think if I would be someone/something  else?) Indeed also the term visualisation can be used in a fruitful way in this context.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by Graham Kemp's answer, I come up with a direct answer.

Consider the set of sequences where the $i$'th draw initiates a color switch (2 possibilities). Cutting out $i$'th and $i+1$'st draws, with two possible subsequences `WB` and `BW`, from each of these sequences generates a unique sequence of draws from $b-1$ black balls and $w-1$ white balls. Conversely inserting `WB` and `BW` between the $i-1$'th and $i$'th draws of each sequence of draws from $b-1$ black balls and $w-1$ white balls generates two distinct sequences of draws from $b$ black balls and $w$ white balls. The $(b,w)$ sequences thus generated are all distinct. The $(b-1,w-1)$ sequences are all equally probable. Thus the total number of $(b,w)$ sequences with a color switch initiating at draw $i$ is $2 {b+w-2\choose b-1}$. The total number of $(b,w)$ sequences is $b+w\choose b$. The probability is then $2\frac b{b+w}\frac w{b+w-1}$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more direct solution than my first one. The probability of getting a black ball on any draw is $\frac b{b+w}$ because by labeling the balls there is an equal probability of a specifically labeled ball as any other emerging out of any given draw. This can also be seen by using the characteristic function of a labeled ball falling on the $i$'th draw and the linearity of the expectation function. By the same token, given the first of two consecutive draws being a black ball, the immediate second draw is equivalent to have a white ball out of a specific draw for $b-1$ black balls and $w$ white balls ensemble. That conditional probability is then $\frac w{b+w-1}$. There are $2$ sequences to realize the color switch, namely `WB` and `BW`. So the probability of a color switch occurring starting on any arbitrary draw is $2\frac b{b+w}\frac w{b+w-1}$.